# Maven Plugin: accessing resources accross multiple modules

Tags: java, maven, maven-mojo

I'm currently writing a custom maven plugin for generating a XML file in a multi-module maven project.

My maven structure is pretty standard: one parent project and a module by project components in the parent project folder:

```
-- Parent
  -- module A
  -- module B
  -- module C
```

I need to list, by module, a set of classes flagged by a custom annotation.
I already wrote a set of custom annotations and an annocation processor to create a XML file at compile time in the corresponding module output directory (${project.build.outputDirectory}) .

Now i need to merge each module XML into one file, but i don't know how to access each modules from within my maven plugin except having each path set as parameters (i don't like this method).

Any idea on how to do this ?
Does maven plugins can traverse project modules ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: introduce a new module under the same parent, and add all other modules as dependencies to make sure the build order, then in that new module you can access all those resources by specifying the relative location , ex ../module a/target/xmla.xml , if you dont like to go with that solution you can expose these xml as a artifact of each module and this new module can refer that artifact as a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list list of all projects you can use:

```java
List<MavenProject> projectList = MavenSession.getProjectDependencyGraph().getSortedProjects()
```

If one of your goals is correctly executed you will get everything you need. Every MavenProject contains a `getBaseDir()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

After some researches, it seems that MavenProject.getCollectedProjects() will return the list of projects beeing manipulated by a goal execution in a multi-module project.

Comment: In fact collected projects only return projects in submodules if they was marked as dependency